# Reuse an iMac's fusion drive?

Tags: macos, imac, hardware, fusion-drive

I have a 2013 iMac with a broken logic board and display. It's too expensive to repair, but I'd like to salvage the fusion drive. If I put the drive in an external case will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Fusion Drive is a combination of 2 drives, one Solid State (SSD) and the other a standard Hard Drive (HDD). You can remove the two drives and reuse them in enclosures as 2 separate drives.

Comment: Thanks. Will the data be intact? where is the directory?

Comment: Sorry, I believe the data from a fusion drive is lost when changes are made to it. But give it a try, I could be wrong.

Comment: @ParadisePete Actually - both volumes would work if connected to another Mac OS operating system. Both drives will be primarily core storage volumes and combined, the two mount as the "Macintosh HD" so you could easily copy files off or keep using it as a "fusion drive"

Answer (score 1):

No, the Fusion Drive will not work away from a Mac.  The separate components can be formatted to work as stand alone drives but the core storage volume that we call a Fusion Drive will not function without OS X.

The data is gone once the Fusion Drive is busted.  You cannot recover data once the drive components cease to be associated as a Fusion Drive.

Comment: Technically correct, but it's viable to reuse the "fusion" setup on any Mac running OS X. Also, you could erase each of the drives and then have two independent drives. +1 for the advice even though the "fusion" stays bound to each other until you explicitly erase it. OS X will warn you but other OS might break that linkage being unaware of how Apple allocates core storage.